# PhoneGap 2.0 Splash always using default

Tags: cordova

I recently did a fresh install of PhoneGap 2.0 and so far I've managed to get almost everything working.  (Rather than try to upgrade my PhoneGap 1.6 app, I just started fresh)

I'm able to get the app icon set to a custom icon, but so far every attempt to set a custom splash has failed.  Out of sheer frustration I set all of the images in res/splash to the same image, I've updated config.xml to point to my custom splash, and I even nuked www/res/.  At this point I don't understand how Phonegap is even finding a default splash to show, unless it is hard-coded as a default.

Has anyone else had trouble setting a custom splash in PhoneGap 2.0?   (Not PhoneGap Build)

EDIT:

I've also gone to the .xcodeproj dialog's Summary tab and have set the App Icons and Launch Images for iPhone/iPod.  They visually reflect my custom splash screen and icon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had similar problem. When I deleted the app from (simulator or device), cleaned build and ran again, it worked.

Comment: Yep, it actually fixed itself for me.  After I archived the app and distributed it, I was surprised to see the custom splash.  After that, when I did a Run, the splash started reflecting.  Weird...  Thanks Kiran!

Comment: Just want to say that this could be useful for all kinds of non-update of something. Icon, app name, splash image, etc. It seems that this is a problem of phonegap.

Comment: I think deleting the app is the key here. I've tried cleaning on its own, it hasn't worked... but removing the app and running again did the trick.

Comment: I concur with @JustinRussell I just tried cleaning, didn't do anything, but delete then clean seems to have worked perfectly.