# Default splash image in iOS Phone Gap / Cordova 2.2.0

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

Question based on: [PhoneGap 2.0 Splash always using default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291233/phonegap-2-0-splash-always-using-default) but that didn't solve it.

Basically my PhoneGap application (version 2.2.0) regardless of what I have done still shows the default Cordova screen. I have replaced:

`/Default-568h@2x.png`, `/Default@2x.png`, `/Default.png`,`/www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png`,`/www/res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png`

I have done a "Clean", a rebuild, I've added a "Launch Image" (UILaunchImageFile) key to the info.plist, I've removed the app from the device and re-built and after all that I still am showing the default Cordova splash image.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bumped into this case also. try to use the xcode file explorer in the left side to copy your new png files. sometimes its just cache it for somereason.. the same with icon's png.

Answer (score 1):

Select Project -> Clean from the menu.  Then rebuild your project.  That should clear out the cached images.